# Polynomials in ring p (p is prime)

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, prime-numbers

I have to prove the following question:

Show that for any prime $p$ and any polynomial $a_0 + a_1 \cdot X + \ldots + a_{n-1} \cdot X^{n-1} + a_n \cdot X^n$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[X]$, we have

$$(a_0 + a_1 \cdot X + \ldots + a_{n-1} \cdot X^{n-1} + a_n \cdot X^n)^p \\= a_0 + a_1 \cdot X^p + \ldots + a_{n-1} \cdot X^{p\cdot (n-1)} + a_n \cdot X^{p\cdot n}$$

I have no idea on how to start, any hints?

Comment: Hint: Start trying it for $n=1$.

Comment: Hint: multinomial theorem.